# How to secure NFS server in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

I'm running NFS server in kubernetes and use this NFS server only for PVC provisioner. So, another pods that is not PVC provisioner or don't use nfs volume provisioned by provisioner actually don't need to be able to access the NFS server. But every pod can access nfs server (through service). Is there a way to restrict access to NFS for only NFS-using pods?

Comment: If you want to control traffic flow or else access at the IP address or port level (OSI layer 3 or 4), then you might consider using Kubernetes NetworkPolicies for particular applications in your cluster. So, for this case the only possible solution is to use [Network policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/), either you need to use separate name space which is having only NFS pods in it or else you can use IP blocks (exception: traffic to and from the node where a Pod is running is always allowed, regardless of the IP address of the Pod or the node).

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Comment: @HemanthKumar Thanks, I didn't know that there is such feature. I'll try using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to control traffic flow at the IP address or port level (OSI layer 3 or 4), then you might consider using Kubernetes NetworkPolicies for particular applications in your cluster. So, for this case the only possible solution is to use [Network policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/), either you need to use separate name spaces which is having only NFS pods in it or else you can use IP blocks (exception: traffic to and from the node where a Pod is running is always allowed, regardless of the IP address of the Pod or the node).